# (Winsock) UDP receive works but send fails for same socket

Tags: c++, udp, winsock

I'm having issues working with a UDP socket in Windows. I have a separate application I'm trying to communicate with that outputs on port 1625 and receives on port 26027. I tried to make a simple executable that reads one message and sends one message. The read works fine, but the send ends up with a WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL (10049) error.

To troubleshoot I also tried the equivalent code in Linux with  (using Windows Subsystem for Linux) on the same machine and it works fine. So I can't figure out what the issue is. I also tried disabling Windows Firewall but that didn't make a difference. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The Windows Visual C++ code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#define MAXLINE 1024

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    // Define local port address.
    sockaddr_in local_port;
    memset(&local_port, 0, sizeof(local_port));
    local_port.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_port.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    local_port.sin_port = htons(1625);

    // Bind local socket.
    int socket_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bind(socket_id, (const struct sockaddr *)&local_port, sizeof(local_port));

    // Receive UDP Port message.
    char in_buffer[MAXLINE];
    int num_bytes = recv(socket_id, (char *)in_buffer, MAXLINE, 0);
    in_buffer[num_bytes] = '\0';
    printf("Received : %s\n", in_buffer);

    // Set up send destination port.
    sockaddr_in dest_port;
    memset(&dest_port, 0, sizeof(dest_port));
    dest_port.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_port.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    dest_port.sin_port = htons(26027);

    // Send UDP message to specific UDP port.
    char out_buffer[] = "Test message";
    int result = sendto(
        socket_id, out_buffer, strlen(out_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_port, sizeof(dest_port));
    printf("Send result : %d -- WSA Error : %d\n", result, WSAGetLastError());

    closesocket(socket_id);
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal output from running this executable is:

```
Received : 5e4009df*755=-0.0028:761=0.6942

Send result : -1 -- WSA Error : 10049
```

The WSL linux C++ code (the same source code except for WSA includes and error output):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAXLINE 1024

int main()
{
    // Define local port address.
    sockaddr_in local_port;
    memset(&local_port, 0, sizeof(local_port));
    local_port.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_port.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    local_port.sin_port = htons(1625);

    // Bind local socket.
    int socket_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bind(socket_id, (const struct sockaddr *)&local_port, sizeof(local_port));

    // Receive UDP Port message.
    char in_buffer[MAXLINE];
    int num_bytes = recv(socket_id, (char *)in_buffer, MAXLINE, 0);
    in_buffer[num_bytes] = '\0';
    printf("Received : %s\n", in_buffer);

    // Set up send destination port.
    sockaddr_in dest_port;
    memset(&dest_port, 0, sizeof(dest_port));
    dest_port.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_port.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    dest_port.sin_port = htons(26027);

    // Send UDP message to specific UDP port.
    char out_buffer[] = "Test message";
    int result = sendto(
        socket_id, out_buffer, strlen(out_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_port, sizeof(dest_port));
    printf("Send result : %d\n", result);

    close(socket_id);
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal output from running this executable is:

```
Received : 5e4009df*755=-0.0028:761=0.6942

Send result : 12
```

I can also validate that the output to port 26027 via this Linux implementation is received by the other application and can also see it in Wireshark.

**EDIT:**
After Remy's answer below I was able to get this working as per the comments below. To clarify my network:

My network if I view it with Wireshark now looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   UDP 50223 → 1625 Len=32  
127.0.0.1   UDP 1625 → 26027 Len=12
```

Where my node binds to 1625 where it can `recv()` UDP from some unknown port number (50223 in this case), and `sendto()` port 26027.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `recv()` with a UDP socket unless you first call `connect()` to statically assign the peer's IP/port to the socket, which you are not doing. So `recv()` will fail, but you are not checking for that. You need to use `recvfrom()` instead.

Also, no matter what, you can't send packets to `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) as you are. That is why you are getting the send error.

[sendto Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto)

> WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL
>
> The remote address is not a valid address, **for example, ADDR_ANY**.

[Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2)

> WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL
>   10049
>
> Cannot assign requested address. **The requested address is not valid in its context**. This normally results from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for the local computer. **This can also result from connect, sendto, WSAConnect, WSAJoinLeaf, or WSASendTo when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0)**.

You need to send to an actual IP/port, such as to the peer's IP/port that is reported by `recvfrom()` when it receives a packet.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was not specifying an IP address in the send. This was being done over localhost (127.0.0.1) so perhaps the linux implementation defaulted to that but winsock did not which is why only one version worked. I also found the guide at http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/ very helpful in differentiating bind/connect and modernizing my set up to use `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: Maybe there was a disconnect in my wording, but `connect()` didn't work for me with `recv()`, but `bind()` was working fine -- the received strings I listed as results in my question were what was expected.  
  
My network if I view it with Wireshark now looks like:  
127.0.0.1 UDP 50223 → 1625 Len=32  
127.0.0.1 UDP 1625 → 26027 Len=12  
  
Where my node binds to 1625 where it can `recv()` UDP from some unknown port number (50223 in this case), and `sendto()` port 26027.

Comment: If you use `recv` without calling `connect`, you will have no idea where the datagrams you receive came from. Usually, you need to know that to send replies.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I suppose my use case is less traditional, and I'm only interested in one-way communications per port. I'm trying to interface with a flight simulation game that runs a lua script and has been set up to publish TO a specific port, and it listens for inputs on another port. So I bind my socket to where data is being published to so I can listen. For a more secure connection it looks like there is a bind->listen->accept sequence I could potentially be doing as well.

Comment: @cjtytler `connect()` is required to use `recv()` and `send()`, but not to use `recvfrom()` and `sendto()`. You should be using `recvfrom()` so you can discover which peer is sending packets to you. Also, `accept()` only works with TCP, you can't use it with UDP.

Comment: Ok I see now in the docs where `recv()` specifies a "connected socket" as it's argument and `recvfrom()` specifies a "bound socket". I'll switch to using `recvfrom()` in my application. Thanks for replying.